# Excel VBA: How to prevent Custom Status Bar Message killing Copy/Paste

Tags: excel, vba

I found some code for messing around with the Status Bar and managed to get it working from a custom addin, but in the process I've accidentally stopped copy and paste from working!

Whenever I change the selection, it loses the 'Copied' selection, so there is nothing to paste.

My question is... how do I prevent the below code from interfering with the current selection?

Edit1: Added in referenced function code

## ThisWorkbook

```
Private WithEvents App As Application

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set App = Application
End Sub

Private Sub App_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Call cellLengthStatusBar
End Sub
```

## Code Module

```
Option Base 1

Public rngTarget As Range
Public cellLength As Long

Public Sub cellLengthStatusBar()

Dim dim1 As Long, dim2 As Long
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Set rngTarget = columnSelectionToRange(Selection)
If rngTarget.Rows.Count > 1 Or rngTarget.Columns.Count > 1 Then
    For dim1 = 1 To rngTarget.Rows.Count
        For dim2 = 1 To rngTarget.Columns.Count
            If Len(rngTarget(dim1, dim2)) > cellLength Then _
                cellLength = Len(rngTarget(dim1, dim2))
        Next dim2
    Next dim1
    Application.statusBar = "MAX CELL LEN: " & cellLength
Else
    Application.statusBar = "CELL LEN: " & Len(rngTarget)
End If
End Sub
```

## Function Module

```
Public Function columnSelectionToRange(Target As Range) As Range
    Dim firstRow As Long, lastRow As Long
    On Error GoTo fail
    firstRow = Target.Row
    If Target.Address = Target.EntireColumn.Address Then
        firstRow = Target.Row + 1
        lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, Target.Column).End(xlUp).Row
    Else: lastRow = Target.Rows.Count + firstRow - 1
    End If
    Set columnSelectionToRange = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(firstRow, Target.Column), Cells(lastRow, Target.Column + Target.Columns.Count - 1))
    'Debug.Print columnSelectionToRange.Address
fail:
End Function
```

Comment: I don't know if it will fix your problem, but I would read the entire `Selection` into a `Variant` array and work with that, instead of looping over the cells individually.

Comment: I tried that but it was giving me grief stating "arrTarget = rngTarget"

Comment: What does "give me grief" entail? An error message?